# Please explain this jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

Perhaps my last question (now deleted) was misunderstood so I'm reposting it with more clarity this time:

jQuery(UI):

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { 
        alert(ui.panel.id);
        $('input[name=myinput], textarea[name=myinput]').attr('disabled', true); 
        $('input[name=myinput].' + ui.panel.id + ', textarea[name=myinput].' + ui.panel.id).removeAttr('disabled'); 
        $('input[name=source]').val(ui.panel.id);
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#direct">Direct input</a></li>
        <li><a href="#files">File upload</a></li>
        <li><a href="#uri">URI</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="direct">
        <textarea name='myinput' class='direct'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="file">
       <input type='file' name='myinput' class='file' />
    </div>
    <div id="uri">
       <input type='text' name='myinput' class='uri' />
    </div>
</div>
<input type='hidden' name='source' value='direct' />
<input type='submit' value='GO' />
```

I don't quite understand what the jQuery is doing with the input. I want to use regular jQuery and avoid the "jQueryUI" tabs so its important that I understand what happening with the input to I can reproduce the same effect when I use regular jQuery. 
Hope I'm making sense.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are are using Regualar Jquery then you can not use tab by default. You a have to write your own code for using Tabs. So your question is what? YOu do not need to use tab here? or you want to write your own codes for Tabs?

Comment: Yes, I want to use my own code for tabs, and its ready, I just don't understand the input/source part. Tabs are working but the input/source is not handles as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `select` function is called:

```
$('input[name=myinput], textarea[name=myinput]').attr('disabled', true);
```

Find all `input` and `textarea` elements named `myinput` and disable them.

```
$('input[name=myinput].' + ui.panel.id + ', textarea[name=myinput].' + ui.panel.id).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Find any `input` elements and `textarea` elements with the name `myinput` **and** the class that matches the value of the `ui.panel.id` property and enable them.

```
$('input[name=source]').val(ui.panel.id);
```

Find the `input` element (or elements, but I bet there's only one) with the name `source` and set its value to the value of the `ui.panel.id` property.

**E.g.:** Disable all of the `myinput` `input` and `textarea` elements *except* the one matching the `ui.panel.id` property according to its class, and set the value of the `input` named `source` to that property, presumably to keep track of which inputs are enabled / which tab is showing.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. How do I modify this (http://jsfiddle.net/mPv8n/) to work the same? Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Nimbuz: You could actually use the code above if you like. Just make sure the inputs and textareas use the name and class conventions above: The names should be `myinput`, and the class should be the ID of the tab you want them shown on. (I probably wouldn't use the `name` attribute like that, I'd probably use either another class name or a `data-tabid` attribute, since you'll probably want to actually use `name` in your form!)

Comment: Erm..thats where I'm stuck. Can you please update that jsfiddle? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`.tabs()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is a jQuery UI plugin that turns the markup you just gave into a tabbed browsing interface.  You could write your own `tabs()` function in jQuery if you wished, but you could easily [download a custom build of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download).  Deselect everything, then select tabs (which only requires Core and Widget)...

If you already have your tabs replacement, T.J. put together a solid answer describing what the `select` event handler is doing.  It is fired every time you select a new active tab.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under the mistaken impression that jQuery UI is a version of jQuery.  It is, in fact, a jQuery plugin.  It's fairly heavyweight, weighing in at many kilobytes.  To reproduce the jquery ui tab code without using jquery ui would be a significant effort.  The code you've shown us is simply calling jquery ui to create the tabs, but the tab plugin is doing a massive amount of work behind the scenes.  You may wish to rethink your desire to move away from jquery ui.

Comment: In that case, starting with the jquery tab plugin is massive overkill.  I don't expect there's much to learn there, because there's an entire abstraction system between you and what it's doing.  I'd go straight to http://api.jquery.com and look at the dom manipulation functions you'll need.